# How can I change the ripple color for a QML Button when it is pressed?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I tried:

```
Button {
  // ...
  Material.highlightedRippleColor: "red"
  // ...
}
```

> Invalid property assignment: "highlightedRippleColor" is a read-only property

I can create my own custom implementation of [Button](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/material/Button.qml), but was hoping this was not necessary.

I am using QtQuick 2.12.

Comment: `Material` as in `qquickmaterialstyle_p.h` only has a getter function, but not a setter. `Q_PROPERTY(QColor highlightedRippleColor READ highlightedRippleColor NOTIFY paletteChanged FINAL)`. So you need to create your own button implementation.
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtquickcontrols2/src/imports/controls/material/qquickmaterialstyle_p.h.html#83